# MySQL Doing sum of nested JSON values

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have a field in a table called duration that contains a JSON string like this:

```
{ 
    "videos": {
        "en":"00:03:11",
        "es":"00:03:11"
    },
    "audios": {
        "en":"00:00:03",
        "es":"00:00:03"
    }
}
```

Is it possible to execute a query to sum all the values of both `videos` and `audio` keys using the possible langauges? Meaning that given this JSON structure, I'd like a query to return:
`00:06:28`

EDIT:

Don't mind the format of the values for the moment, there are ways to sum datetime values in SQL. What I'm struggling with now is to traverse the values in the JSON to actually sum them.

Comment: How do you suppose you would sum those values, even if they weren't stored in JSON?

Comment: @BillKarwin I edited my post, there are ways to sum datetime values, so that wouldn't be a bigger problem than actually looping through the JSON values to sum them. I initially thought of making a mysql function but I'm not that good with SQL

Comment: Are you using MySQL 5.7 or later? Have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html and tried out the functions?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.7.23.